# How do you fill with 0 a dynamic matrix, in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic, matrix

How do you fill with 0 a dynamic matrix, in C++? I mean, without:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)for(int j=0;j<n;j++)a[i][j]=0;
```

I need it in O(n), not O(n*m) or O(n^2).
Thanks.

Comment: That's not physically possible.

Comment: How do you write to n^2 memory locations in O(n) time? With magic?

Comment: That's impossible. You can however use `std::fill` to reduce the constant. Most compilers optimize that to a `memset` call.

Comment: You can use one-dimensional array for store matrix and fill that array by zeroes using `memset()`

Comment: Thanks, that was the answear I was expecting. :)

Comment: @floriniell this is still in O(n^2) for a n x n matrix ...

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case where your array is going to to be large and sparse and you want to zero it at allocation time then you can get some benefit from using `calloc` - on most platforms this will result in lazy allocation with zero pages, e.g.

```
int **a = malloc(n * sizeof(a[0]);     // allocate row pointers
int *b = calloc(n * n, sizeof(b[0]);   // allocate n x n array (zeroed)

a[0] = b;                              // initialise row pointers
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
{
    a[i] = a[i - 1] + n;
}
```

Note that this is, of course, premature optimisation. It is also C-style coding rather than C++. You should only use this optimisation if you have established that performance is a bottleneck in your application and there is no better solution.

Comment: The question doesn't specify "initialize a new matrix". The OP might want to fill an existing matrix.

Comment: @KerrekSB: true - if you need to re-initialise an existing array then obviously there is no short cut, but it might still be more efficient to free it and reallocate it as above, if it's going to be fairly sparse. (For non-sparse data then there is nothing to be gained.)

Comment: Using zero pages feels like cheating. You're not really creating any objects; it's more like you're replacing an object with an instruction how to obtain its value. Still, that's an incredibly useful feature.

Comment: At the end of the day it's all smoke and mirrors... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)for(int j=0;j<n;j++)a[i][j]=0;
```

I assume, that your matrix is two dimensional array declared as either

```
int matrix[a][b];
```

or

```
int** matrix;
```

In first case, change this `for` loop to a single call to [memset()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/):

```
memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(int) * a * b);
```

In second case, you will to do it this way:

```
for(int n = 0; n < a; ++n)
    memset(matrix[n], 0, sizeof(int) * b);
```

On most platforms, a call to `memset()` will be replaced with proper compiler intrinsic.

Comment: If the declaration is `int** matrix`, the `memset` will blow up.

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. Arrays are not pointers. Freedom is slavery.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, you're right of course. Fixed this up.

Comment: Both versions have runtime O(n^2). There is no magical free work in either version.

Answer (score 0):

every nested loop is not considered as O(n2)
the following code is a O(n),

> No 1
> `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)for(int j=0;j<n;j++)a[i][j]=0;`

imagine that you had all of the cells in matrix `a` copied into a one dimentional flat array and set zero for all of its elements by just one loop, what would be the order then? ofcouse you will say thats a O(n)

> No 2 `for(int i=0;i<n*m;i++) b[i]=0;`

Now lets compare them, *No 2* with *No 1*,  ask the following questions from yourselves :

- Does this code traverse matrix a cells more than once?
- If I can measure the time will there be a difference?

Both answers are NO.

## Both codes are O(n), A multi-tier nested loop on a multi-dimentional array produces a O(n) order.